# if Video View creates delay for video view show message for user 

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-videoview

I am developing a Live video streaming application for android. For video playing I am just passing the `URL`  for `VideoView`. Most of the times video is playing well. But sometimes   when server is down,I found `VideoView` is not prepared for playing the video and its continuously showing black screen.

I want to implement a tracker for `VideoView`. Suppose if `VideoView` doesn't show video for 10 seconds,a `Dialog box` will appear with message, and when I click on the OK button, `Activity` will finish.

Anybody suggest some ideas or code to implement my idea?

Comment: I got the solution. I done it. With the help of handler, i showed alert after specific time. if videoview is prepared for video play i make a call to dismiss the alert dialog.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should be using the [`setOnPreparedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnPreparedListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener%29) to check on the preparedness of your `VideoView`.
- You can look out for errors using : `setOnErrorListener()`.
- And you can keep an eye on the buffering percentage using :`getBufferPercentage()`. If the [media source has not](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) ended playback, it could mean you have a buffering problem, if your buffering percentage has stagnated at a certain level.

Comment: For me `getBufferingPercentage()` returns `0` until the move starts to play. Once the movie is playing the buffering percent is always `80`...... not very useful (MOTO XOOM - streaming video).